# Does CreateOrReplaceTempView use the same data of dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When we create a temp view from a dataframe,

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
```

Does the view use the same data of the dataframe, or does it copy all data of dataframe ?

I could not find an answer to this question in spark sql documentation or stackoverflow questions, only usage and scope of view is discussed.

Comment: No reason to copy all, it is same.

Comment: @Lamanus yes I agree, but is this what it is done actually ?

Comment: For the moment, I found that creating the temp view use the same logical plan as the one to build the dataframe. So if the execution of logical plan ignores its previous executions (to be verified) at this time the view will generate new data.